# How to make text color blue in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to make my text blue but I don't know how to. I need help, I tried 
  `<blue></blue>`  around it but doesn't work.

Comment: seriously? and nothing found on google?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the very basic usage of CSS that can be found within 5sec doing a Google search (faster than writing the question)

Comment: i new i didnt find anything

Comment: put your title on google and you will find a ton of things

Comment: ohh right sorry

Comment: I just see that right now

Comment: While this question is trivial to answer with a Google search, that doesn't make it inherently *off-topic* or close-worthy. I can't immediately find where this question has been asked before on Stack Overflow (and has not also been deleted); unless a dupe is found, this will remain technically an on-topic question. With that being said, that does not mean it's not downvote-worthy for lack of research effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try  CSS `*{color: blue;}`-Put that into your style tags. `<blue></blue>`is not a valid tag.